# How do I retrieve value in Column B Given 2 Criteria on the Same Row in an excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, index-match

I have a table similar to the one below and am trying to get column B data based on the criteria in Column A and C.  A = UserID, B = Description, C = Cost_Priority, D Cost.  The table lists each userID, and common problem description, ranking the cost for the problem description and the cost of the problem description. This is a supplied table that I am working from.

| UserID | Problem_Description | Cost_Priority | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Problem A | 1 | 395.00 |
| 111 | Problem B | 2 | 200.00 |
| 111 | Problem C | 0 | 150.00 |
| 111 | Problem D | 0 | 145.00 |
| 112 | Problem G | 1 | 800.73 |
| 112 | Problem S | 2 | 200.46 |
| 112 | Problem T | 0 | 100.51 |

Resulting Table should look like the one below where UserID is Given along with the columns
that define the Cost Priority Required. The problem I am having is getting the problem description
based on static values in the User ID columns static values of 1 for Highest cost problem and 2 for the 2nd highest cost problem.

| UserID | Highest Cost Problem | 2nd Highest Cost Problem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Problem A | Problem B |
| 112 | Problem G | Problem S |

I have tried using a vlookup method to grab the USERID and compare Cost_Priority to 1 or 2 in an if statement but it was returning the Problem Description column in order including where Cost Priority was 0.  I was wondering if someone else had any other ideas to populate the 2nd and 3rd columns in the 2nd table.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on ***Microsoft 365*** then try below formula. Drag down and across as needed.

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER($B$2:$C$8,($A$2:$A$8=$A12)*($C$2:$C$8>0)),2,1),COLUMN(A$1),1)
```

For older versions of excel try below array formula-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$8=$A12)*($C$2:$C$8=COLUMN(A$1)),0))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]